# How can I detect in a Xamarin Forms - Entry which key has the user typed?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I would like to eventually bring out a display message if the user has made invalid input

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

use [TextChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#textchanged)

```
<Entry TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged" />

void Entry_TextChanged (object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var oldText = e.OldTextValue;
    var newText = e.NewTextValue;
}
```